# validating a form using bootstrap with spring framework hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, twitter-bootstrap

so i have this form and it needs a validation and i am using a bootstrap but now i am trying to insert the values to my database using hibernate but it won't allow me because it is requiring the "required autofocus"or "required" a equal sign and i don't see any documentation on bootstrap how to validate my form.. do i need now to validate my form using javascript? i hope someone can help me here is my code

```
<c:url var="actionUrl" value="save" />
    <form:form id="registerForm" commandName="users" method="post" action="${actionUrl }" class="form-horizontal" >
        <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="email">Email</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
            <form:input path="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" type="email" required autofocus />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="username">Username</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
            <form:input path="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" type="username" required />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="password">Password</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
            <form:input path="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" type="password" required />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="location">Location</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <form:select path="location" class="form-control" type="location" >
                <option>France</option>
                <option>Amsterdam</option>
                <option>Philippines</option>
                <option>Others</option>
            </form:select>

            <form:input path="userId" type="hidden" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="register">Register</button>
            <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">Cancel</button> 
        </div><!-- end modal-footer -->
        </fieldset>
    </form:form>
```

Comment: Have you added validation to Bootstrap modal window? if so, how did you avoid modal window closing after submit?

Answer (score 1):

just add
`<form:errors path="username" />`
and so on for all input fields.. it worked for me